ngx- chart line chart tootip disabled on all series but one
I am building a ngx-chart with multiple lines in it, but I want only the first line to display tooltps, while the others should have the tooltip disabled behaviour, not being interactable or showing the points on mouseover. I tried changing the [tooltipDisabled] property but it seems to work only for the whole chart and not on singular lines.
My chart is the following:
<ngx-charts-line-chart  [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" 
[legend]="legend" [showYAxisLabel]="false"
[legendPosition]="getChartLegendPositionNew()" legendTitle="" 
[animations]="false" [showXAxisLabel]="false"
[xAxis]="true" [xAxisTickFormatting]="dateTickFormatting" 
[xScaleMin]="startDate" [xScaleMax]="endDate"
[yAxis]="true" [curve]="curve"
[results]="allTrendData" (select)="selectTrend($event)">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>

Is there a way to achieve what I set out to do?
